# Use on "Adapter" for two (or more) parent views?

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner, android-adapter

Is it possible to use one adapter class (and it's instance) (e.g. own sub-class of `ArrayAdapter<ownDataType>` for two (or more) different views?

In my `Activity`,  I have two `Spinner` objects that are used to show (and select) related data: A list of parent categories and a list of sub-categories of the selected parent category. Of course, the list in the sub-category-`Spinner` is updated (setting a new `ArrayAdapter`), when the parent category is changed. However, I also want to be able to set a sub-category directly (and choose the parent category automatically) when the Activity is created. This makes things complicated.

My idea for a simple and clean solution now is to create ONE own Adapter-Class (e.g. derived from `ArrayAdapter<CategoryPair>`, where `CategoryPair` is a simple class that holds a pair of parent- and sub-category) and this own adapter class handles all the logic to keep data consistent (much simpler there).

In the `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method of the `Adapter`-class I need to recognize reliably for which of the two `Spinner` objects in my activity I need to create a view.

Can I rely on the `parent` parameter?

Do you think my idea is a good one?

*Edit:* Code example:

My adapter class:

```
public class CategoryPair
{
    Category parent;        
    Category sub;
}

public class CategoriesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CategoryPair> {
    private Spinner parentSpinner;
    private Spinner subSpinner;
    public CategoriesAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, Spinner par, Spinner sub) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        parentSpinner = par;
        subSpinner = sub;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (parent == parentSpinner)
        {
            //
        }
        else if (parent == subSpinner)
        {
            //
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Invalid parent in CategoriesAdapter");
        }                   
        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, that's fine. Each view should use a different *instance* of your Adapter (make sure of this), so, unless your Adapter code is buggy and uses static variables, everything should work just fine.

Comment: No, I mean to use the same instance of the class for the two `Spinner`s of my `Activity`. So each `Activity` instance uses *one* `Adapter` instance for two of it's `Spinner`s. I'll post a code sample this evening (CET).

Comment: I'm not sure if the underlying adapter code would let you do that, but anyway, I don't think that would be standard practice. You can control the currently selected object in the view, which would be the ideal way to do what I think you want to do.